# Problem copying files from PC to Galaxy S3 (slow or frozen)

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, usb, file-transfer

I have a lot of difficulty copying files to my Galaxy S3. My goal is to sync my music from MediaMonkey to my GS3. When I connect the phone, the computer sees it but the connection is incredibly slow! And it is the same thing if I copy files using Windows Explorer or MediaMonkey. The files start to copy, it takes maybe about 1 minute per song, and at some point it will slow down, then stop to progress and freeze.

I made sure I was using the stock USB cable provided with my device but I also tried 2 other cables with same results. The last thing I tried was to clear the cache partition then reboot. I also tried different USB ports on the PC (USB2 and 3, different controllers).

I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Are you copying it to the phone, or the external SD card? If it's the latter, much faster if you plug it into an SD card reader/writer, or make sure you are in mass storage mode, instead of MTP.

Comment: And in both cases, you might still wish to try it via WiFi, using e.g. [FolderSync](http://www.appbrain.com/app/foldersync-lite/dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite), [Wifi File Transfer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Wifi-File-Transfer/com.my186soft.filemanager), [WebSharing](http://www.appbrain.com/app/WebSharingLite-File-Media-Sync/nextapp.websharing), or a similar app.

Comment: @geffchang I'm copying to the phone internal memory so I cannot use mass storage.

Comment: @Izzy I thought about using a wireless transfer method but MediaMonkey detects the device connected to USB and syncs the songs and playlists in the right format for the GS3. If I just copy files I'm not able to keep the playlists.

Comment: I don't know MediaMonkey, but from your comment I assume it requires a "drive letter" to work. Maybe some "server" on your Android device could help accomplishing that via WiFi (I'm thinking about [DavDrive](http://www.appbrain.com/app/DavDrive/de.fun2code.android.webdrive), [Droid NAS](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Droid-NAS/com.codesector.droidnas), and the like).

Comment: @Izzy Good point but I don't think that MediaMonkey would then recognize the device as the GS3. For instance, another option I considered was to export my music on an micro SD card and then to copy from card to phone internal memory. However this was resulting in playlists and cover images not being supported on the GS3. I didn't find a way to make the app export GS3 format on a generic drive letter.

Comment: I see. In that case I'm out. Hopefully somebody else might have more (and better fitting) ideas.

Comment: But your different proposals seem to be a great alternative for the cases where a user would like to copy other types of files. And I think my question was more about using the USB port to copy files in general, MediaMonkey was more an example of what I was experiencing. So you could add your comments as an answer and I will accept it if nothing better comes up in a few weeks.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Dropbox and other cloud based storage, very useful for moving files.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I use Dropbox myself as well but the issue I am trying to solve is the slow copy over USB. I would not be able to transfer 20+ Gb of data over the free Dropbox account anyway.

Comment: And by the way I didn't mod down you answer. It is a valid alternative but just not suitable for what I want to achieve.