# Can't copy files from Windows to Android?

Tags: file-transfer

I have a Galaxy 5s with a 32GB external card, which I connect to my Windows 7 x64 PC with a USB 2.0 cable.   I can copy files **from** my phone to the PC all day long with no problems.  Copying files **to** the phone from the PC is virtually impossible, however.

I can open the phone's card in Windows Explorer, and look at all the files.   But trying to copy anything onto the card hangs explorer.  Right now I'm trying to copy a 42MB MP3 file from my PC to the phone - it's telling me "27 minutes to go" and it's already taken half an hour.

I checked [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/53839/problem-copying-files-from-pc-to-galaxy-s3-slow-or-frozen) from 2013 which seems like the same problem, but basically the answers were "you can't get there from here."   Was wondering if anyone had a solution for this.

Comment: Is copying to the phone's internal storage feasible?

Comment: have you tried adb/ftp/methods?

Comment: Can't really copy to the phone's internal storage, it's nearly full.   I don't want to fill it up completely and risk corrupting all my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a fast solution I would recommend [FTPServer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lutey.FTPServer&hl=de) as mentioned above.I had a similar problem and that was the drivers from Samsung.Maybe a little driver upgrade would solve your problem . [Google USB Driver](https://dl-ssl.google.com//android/repository/latest_usb_driver_windows.zip)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try upgrading the driver and see if that helps!

Comment: It is definitely a driver problem - tried it on another PC and it worked fine.  So, Android is off the hook and it's Windows.   I will keep looking and post any additional information.

Answer (score 1):

I've got 3 possible solutions.

1) If your drivers and Android OS are up to date, I would simply purchase a microSD card adapter and insert it directly into your PC. This avoids the problem alltogether.

2) On the free side of things, you can upload the file you want from your PC to google drive (or other cloud service) and download it to your phone.

3) The problem might be with your SDcard. You might want to verify that it is the capacity it says it is. Sometimes cards are counterfeit and will be only 2gb or less in size. You can use H2testw to verify what the actual size is.

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 to Samsung A32 Card: I can copy files from a USB stick inserted in the Windows 7 PC to the Android card. I cannot copy files directly from the PC hard disk to the Android.

So I can copy from the PC to an inserted USB stick and then from the USB stick to the Android!